# Js for making a search bar /How do I make "no match" appear only after the user has finished typing in their search?/

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, display

When I still typing such as "De" the list below will show "Demi" & "no match" but I still typing so How do I make "no match" appear only after the user has finished typing in their search?

```js
usernameInput.addEventListener("keyup",function(){
    const usernameInput = document.getElementById("usernameInput")
    let userName = event.target.value.toLowerCase()
    let allNamesDOMCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("name")
    for(var count=0; count <  allNamesDOMCollection.length;count++) {
    const currentName = allNamesDOMCollection[count].textContent.toLowerCase()
    if(currentName.includes(userName))
      {allNamesDOMCollection[count].style.display = "block";
       const nomatch = document.getElementById("nomatch");
       nomatch.style.display = "none"
      }
      else
      {
       allNamesDOMCollection[count].style.display = "none"; 
       const nomatch = document.getElementById("nomatch");
       nomatch.style.display = "block"
      }
      
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  width: 900px;
  margin:0 auto
}

.container {
  border: 3px solid;
  margin: 2rem 0rem
}

/* searchbar */

.searchbar {
  display:flex;
  background-color: orange;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.searchbar {
  padding: 2rem;
}

#usernameInput {
  margin-left:1rem;
  width: 30%;
}


/* namelist */


.namelist {
  background-color: rgba(16,95,229,.8);
  padding: 1rem;
  
}

.liststar {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding-left:0;
}

li {
  background-color: white;
  margin:0.5em;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size:1.2rem;
  text-align:center;
}

#nomatch {
  display:none
}
```

```html
<html>
  
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="searchbar">
      <label for="usernameInput">Search Users</label>
    <input id="usernameInput" type="text">
    
    </div>
   <div class="namelist">
     <ul class="liststar">
       <li class="name">Demi</li>
       <li class="name">Joe</li>
       <li class="name">Jojo</li>
       <li class="name">Lily</li>
       <li class="name">Tata</li>
       <li class="name">Momo</li>
       <li class="name">Dad</li>
       <li class="name">Sister</li>
       <li id="nomatch"> no match</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>
```

Comment: How would you know they are done typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you are hiding/showing "no match" upon each loop iteration (each word in the list), where you need to make that decision after the loop is finished and you've checked all the words. So move `nomatch.style.display = ...` so that it is after the loop and then you'll only be able to set it properly if you know if there was a match during the loop, so you'll need a variable to keep track of that.

Additionally, your code uses some older syntax and can be simplified quite a bit.

See the comments inline:

```js
// Get your DOM references just once
const nomatch = document.getElementById("nomatch");
const usernameInput = document.getElementById("usernameInput");

// .getElementsByClassName() is bad for performance
let allNamesDOMCollection = document.querySelectorAll(".name");
       
usernameInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(){

  let searchValue = this.value.toLowerCase();
  let itemsFound = false; // Keeps track of any possible matches
  
  // Node lists can be looped over with Array.forEach()
  allNamesDOMCollection.forEach(function(currentName){
    if(currentName.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)){
      currentName.style.display = "block";
      itemsFound = true;
    } else {
      currentName.style.display = "none"; 
    }
  });
  
  // You should only show/hide "no match" after the loop 
  // is done checking all the entries.
  nomatch.style.display = itemsFound ? "none" : "block";
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  width: 900px;
  margin:0 auto
}

.container {
  border: 3px solid;
  margin: 2rem 0rem
}

/* searchbar */

.searchbar {
  display:flex;
  background-color: orange;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.searchbar {
  padding: 2rem;
}

#usernameInput {
  margin-left:1rem;
  width: 30%;
}


/* namelist */


.namelist {
  background-color: rgba(16,95,229,.8);
  padding: 1rem;
  
}

.liststar {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding-left:0;
}

li {
  background-color: white;
  margin:0.5em;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size:1.2rem;
  text-align:center;
}

#nomatch {
  display:none
}
```

```html
<html>
  
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="searchbar">
      <label for="usernameInput">Search Users</label>
    <input id="usernameInput" type="text">
    
    </div>
   <div class="namelist">
     <ul class="liststar">
       <li class="name">Demi</li>
       <li class="name">Joe</li>
       <li class="name">Jojo</li>
       <li class="name">Lily</li>
       <li class="name">Tata</li>
       <li class="name">Momo</li>
       <li class="name">Dad</li>
       <li class="name">Sister</li>
       <li id="nomatch"> no match</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>
```